# Manipulate string in CSV using NiFi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

[image: Sample CSV]

I have CSV file which is coming from PowerTop tool, I need to modify this CSV before uploading it to target location.

I want to start manipulation from row number 13 which is containing string like **Usage;Events/s;Category;Description;PW Estimate**

I'm new to this tool and tried a lot with using so many Nifi processors but no luck.

I want to break it as Usage Events and so on ... using ; as a separator and with their corresponding values like
[image: Desired result]

I tried with UpdateRecord processor as below.
[image]

CSVRecordSetWriter

[image]
Please guide, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I believe you'll need a scripted processor such as ExecuteScript in order to accomplish this. Because the first 12 lines are not in the same format I don't think you can use SampleRecord. I have written up [NIFI-8932](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8932) to cover the addition of a "Skip Top Rows" property to CSVReader and am actively working it.